# React: filter array: Can I work with elements that didn't pass the test?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am working on a React app. In my React app, I have a price list in "Price" popup window that I was able to code to edit, add, or delete each item in the price list. However, I need to modify the delete function to change the status of a button from disable to active.

I had it set up that if I "Add" a price in the "Price" popup window, the "Add" button is now disabled to prevent adding more entries since the price entry is supposed to be limited to one entry per day.

Therefore, the way my delete function is coded is that it filters through the price list and remove the price from the price list.

```
handleDeletePrice = deletePrice => {
   // const { date } = this.props;
   this.setState(prevState => ({
   // spreads out the previous list and delete the price with a unique id
   priceArr: prevState.priceArr.filter(item => item.date !== deletePrice)     
   }));
};
```

What I am attempting to do is to check if the deleted price's date is the same as today's date for the price that was added. If the deleted price's date is today, then I will active the "Add" button in the "Price" popup window so that I can add another today's price.

Here's my attempt that's **not working**:

```
handleDeletePrice = deletePrice => {
  // const { date } = this.props;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    // spreads out the previous list and delete the price with a unique id
    priceArr: prevState.priceArr.filter(item => {
      if (item.date !== deletePrice) {
        return item;
      }
      if (deletePrice == todaydate) {
        return buttonDisabled: true;
      }
    })
  }));
};
```

The `buttonDisabled` is a state.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      priceArr: this.props.pricelist,
      showPricePopup: false,
      addPricePopup: false,
      todaydate: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
      date: props.date || "",
      number: props.number || "",
      buttonDisabled: this.props.buttonStatus
    };
  }
```

Do I need to use a different method to go through the price array such as `forEach` to push the deleted price in another array and then, filter through the deleted array to see if it matches today's date to activate the button?

You can check out my CodeSandBox demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kikidesignnet/caissa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your buttonDisabled flag based upon whether the deletePrice is equal to today's date or not,If it is equal to to today's date then button disabled is false and vice-versa.I tried in the code sandbox and the add button gets enabled again.

Also,deletePrice variable can be  named as deletePriceDate for  better representation.

```
    handleDeletePrice = deletePrice => {
    const { todaydate } = this.state;
    console.log("deletePrice", deletePrice);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      // spreads out the previous list and delete the price with a unique id
      priceArr: prevState.priceArr.filter(item => item.date !== deletePrice),
      buttonDisabled: !(deletePrice === todaydate)
    }));
  };
```

Also,regarding your original function of elements failing the filter test,the lodash library does have a reject function but there is no javascript method as such.

Comment: Thanks! It's now so simple when I was thinking of the solution from a complicated perspective...

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight change in data structure might solve your problem. You can use javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of *priceArr* array. Disabled state of your button depends only on one entry of prices list. Using Map you can just check if entry for particular date exists or not. It will also help in deletion and you can avoid iterating over same array again and again. Please let me know if you need more help with code.